# SVG gradient on rotated elements

Tags: svg, gradient

I'm trying to apply a gradient fill over a few rects rotated to form a circle.
The final result would be something like this
[image]
but with individual, disconnected pieces.
The issue I'm facing is that all of the rects are filled the same.

Here's what i've tried, this is just a minimal example:

```html
<svg width=300px height=300px viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>

        <linearGradient id="notchGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:green;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(50,50)" fill="url(#notchGradient)">
    <g>
        <g transform="rotate(0)">
            <rect x="0" y="-50" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(90)">
            <rect x="0" y="-50" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(180)">
            <rect x="0" y="-50" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(270)">
            <rect x="0" y="-50" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I'm assuming they're the same because they all have 0,-50 coords even though they're at different spots because of the rotation.

So i've also tried putting them at poins around the circle using just coords:

```html
<svg width=300px height=300px overflow=visible viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="notchGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:green;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g fill="url(#notchGradient)">
        <g transform="rotate(0)" style="transform-box:fill-box;transform-origin:center;">
            <rect x="50" y="0" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(90)" style="transform-box:fill-box;transform-origin:center;">
            <rect x="100" y="50" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(180)" style="transform-box:fill-box;transform-origin:center;">
            <rect x="50" y="100" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(270)" style="transform-box:fill-box;transform-origin:center;">
            <rect x="0" y="50" width="2" height="5"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This does seem to apply the gradient, but the problem now is that i somehow need to figure out coords for each one, and if i wanna do one every few degrees this doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: But what should the rectangles look like? Should each of them have a blue, green and red color or it is a "global" gradient where the rectangle to the left should be blue, middle green and right red? In the first case, should the gradient be rotated as well, so the top rectangle is blue, green, red and the bottom is red, green blue?

Comment: Convert your code to a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @chrwahl it should be the "global" one like you've described. applying the same gradient on each one works by just changing gradient units to the default value.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman never asked on SO, so didn't know how to add those. thanks for the link, i've updated the question with the snippets

Answer (score 0):

Fills are applied before transforms, so you can't do what you want with the current structure (it doesn't matter that the fill is defined in the outer g: the fill is inherited by the rect and painted before the transform is applied). You can either convert everything to use a filter - which is applied after a transform, or you can explicitly position each rect and then use a corrected gradient definition - like so:

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="notchGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="120" y2="120" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:green;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g fill="url(#notchGradient)">
       <rect x="50" y="0" width="12" height="15"/>
       <rect x="100" y="50" width="15" height="12"/>
       <rect x="50" y="100" width="12" height="15"/>
       <rect x="0" y="50" width="15" height="12"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Or if you want to use a filter:

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 140 140" >
<defs>
     <linearGradient id="notchGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="140" y2="140" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
     <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:green;stop-opacity:1" />
     <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
   </linearGradient>
  
     <rect id="fullBleed" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="140" fill="url(#notchGradient)" > 
       
      <filter id="gradientMe">
        <feImage x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#fullBleed"/>
        <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>
      
    <g filter = "url(#gradientMe")>
      <g transform="rotate(0 70 70)">
       <rect x="50" y="0" width="42" height="25"/>
       <rect x="100" y="50" width="45" height="22"/>
       <rect x="50" y="100" width="42" height="25"/>
       <rect x="0" y="50" width="45" height="22"/>
      </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: i think this is the same as what i did in the second example (?), just bigger rects. the issue here as i've said is that if want like 100 or so of them instead of 4, manually positioning them seems like a nightmare

Comment: Yes re-read the original - added the filter version (you'll need to inline the input to feImage if you want it to work in Firefox). You're going to have to define lots of different gradients anyway though - that's a polar gradient and it's not supported in SVG 1.1 at least. There are other questions on here asking how to simulate a polar gradient so there should be code you can copy and paste.